# Is this complex logic can be used in spark？

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have some data like follow structure and the size of data is very large. I could not find a suitable logic to use spark.

```
Data1,Data2,Flag
2016-04-29,00:40:15,1
2016-04-29,00:40:24,2
2016-04-29,00:40:35,2
2015-04-29,00:40:36,2
2015-04-29,00:40:43,2
2015-04-29,00:40:45,2
2015-04-29,00:40:55,1
2015-04-29,00:41:05,1
2015-04-29,00:41:16,1
2015-04-29,00:41:17,2
.....................
.....................
2016-11-29,11:52:36,2
2016-11-29,11:52:43,2
2016-11-29,11:52:45,2
2016-11-29,11:52:55,1
```

I want to get the data meet the following requirements.

1.As you know the first data's time series is 2016-04-29,00:40:15. I want to get the next data which is the last data smaller than 18 seconds. I'll get the second data : 2016-04-29,00:40:24,2 The third data is: 2015-04-29,00:40:36,2

2.If the next data's flag is different from the primer's data.I will get this data regardless of whether it is the last data which is smaller than 18 secs.And I will choose this data as the new beginning.

For the above two requirements, I 'll get the data as following:

```
Data1,Data2,Flag
2016-04-29,00:40:15,1
2016-04-29,00:40:24,2    (flag change)
2015-04-29,00:40:36,2    (last smaller than the beginning in 18 secs)
2015-04-29,00:40:55,1    (flag change)
2015-04-29,00:41:05,1    (last smaller than the beginning in 18 secs)
2015-04-29,00:41:17,2    (flag change)
.......................
.......................
```

I don't know how to deal with this logic in spark. Thanks~

Comment: Is your input data coming directly from data stream [ eg kafka, storm] ?

Answer (score 1):

By default Apache Spark doesn't guarantee data ordering and you can't access previous or next element in RDD (Resilient Distributed Dataset). Data could be automagically partitioned across nodes.

You could modify loading script to store data in format where two sequential items are stored in one entity. E.g.:

```
Date1;      Time1;    Flag1; Date2;      Time2;    Flag2
2016-04-29; 00:40:15; 1;     2016-04-29; 00:40:24; 2
2016-04-29; 00:40:24; 2;     2016-04-29; 00:40:35; 2
2016-04-29; 00:40:35; 2;     2015-04-29; 00:40:36; 2
2015-04-29; 00:40:36; 2;     2015-04-29; 00:40:43; 2
2015-04-29; 00:40:43; 2;     2015-04-29; 00:40:45; 2
2015-04-29; 00:40:45; 2;     2015-04-29; 00:40:55; 1
2015-04-29; 00:40:55; 1;     2015-04-29; 00:41:05; 1
2015-04-29; 00:41:05; 1;     2015-04-29; 00:41:16; 1
2015-04-29; 00:41:16; 1;     2015-04-29; 00:41:17; 2
2015-04-29; 00:41:17; 2;     .......................
....................................................
.......................;     2016-11-29; 11:52:36; 2
2016-11-29; 11:52:36; 2;     2016-11-29; 11:52:43; 2
2016-11-29; 11:52:43; 2;     2016-11-29; 11:52:45; 2
2016-11-29; 11:52:45; 2;     2016-11-29; 11:52:55; 1
```

In this sample each line contains pair of values: `Date1`, `Time1`, `Flag1` - are loaded from one element, `Date2`, `Time2`, `Flag2` - from next element in data source. With such scheme you could write simple script to analize diffence in two serial data elements and Spark will run it in a cluster.